# Exif Direction of Picture

Tags: image, exif, geotagging, pyexiv2

I have a bunch of Geotagged pictures that I'm accessing in python using pyexiv2. It's working great except I don't understand what the "GPSImgDirection" value is giving. Basically, it's two great big numbers, for example:

`2147483647/8613474`

What does that mean? I think it's a "rational" data type. What does that mean? How can I turn the number into something people could understand, such as "5 degrees East of North"?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: I make that 249 degrees, or roughly South West. The specification doesn't like floating point numbers because different computers represent them differently. I think it's the direction the camera was looking.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it's just the one number divided by the other? It's just a big fraction?

Comment: I believe so, but would suggest you do a quick check with a few test shots facing a couple of different directions.

Comment: Seems to work! Thanks a lot. If you make it an answer I'll tick it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark correctly informed me that this is just a big fraction. So:

`2147483647/8613474 = 249.3 degrees`

So starting from due North as 0 degrees and going clockwise, it's saying it's roughly SW or W.